# Liberty Spring Boot vs Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, websphere-liberty

What is the difference between Spring's Spring boot package and Liberty profile Spring Boot package(net.wasdev.wlp.starters.springbootweb)?

Did we get any advantage when we use net.wasdev.wlp.starters.springbootweb package with Liberty profile?

Why IBM specific Spring Boot package and what's its significance compare to conventional Spring Boot package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

net.wasdev.wlp.starters.springbootweb is essentially a sample application that demonstrates using spring boot w/ Liberty. It's not an alternative to spring boot.